# how to open port 22 ssh for PuTTY while in repair mode

Tags: dual-boot, ssh, putty

Ubuntu 18.04, Virtual Server at Hosting.
Attempting SSH Putty connection on Port 22 is causing a timeout. Port is closed.
Over the Hosting Service admin panel I can put the Server into 'Repair' mode and can connect to SSH Port 22 via Putty fine.

The filesystem of the 'normal' server is in the /repair/ folder when connected in Repair mode.

Hosting Service provider tells me that I need to issue commands that open port 22 on the /repair/ instance. I am not sure how to do that.

All actions that I do effect the 'Repair' instance and not the 'Normal' Server
for example

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

works on the 'Repair' instance and port 22 is closed again when I reboot in 'Normal' mode from the management interface

How I can I open port 22 for SSH from the Repair instance ? Can it be done with editing text/config files ?

If so can someone provide detailed instructions please

The filesystem of the Repair instance:

> root@h2861449:/# ls bin   dev  home  lib64       media  opt   repair 
>   run   srv  tmp  var boot  etc  lib   lost+found  mnt    proc  root
>   sbin  sys  usr

The filesystem of /repair/

> root@h2861449:/repair# ls aquota.group  bin   dev  home  lib64
>   media  opt             proc  run   srv  tmp  var aquota.user   boot 
>   etc  lib   lost+found  mnt    private-backup  root  sbin  sys  usr

thank you kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable ufw by editing `/repair/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`.

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=no
```

Once disabled you can login normally and add the rule and re-enable ufw.